# RabbitMQ - Creating and managing users dynamically in real-time

Tags: security, rabbitmq

We're evaluating RabbitMQ for a context where many different users would connect to it and have the following questions:

1. Is it feasible to create a RabbitMQ user and set his permissions at runtime for each user of our system that wants to connect to Rabbit and delete this RabbitMQ user after his session is terminated?
2. Even if we have thousands or even millions of users connecting in high volumes?
3. If so, should we use the RabbitMQ Management API (REST)?
4. Instead of enforcing security through RabbitMQ's User and ACL system, should we rather provide each user with an exclusive Exchange with a random (some kind of session key) name that can't be guessed by other the other users?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit - Clarification**

Each user that connects to our system should only be able to write to and read from certain dynamically created queues or exchanges. We don't want unauthorized users to be able to subscribe to other people's queues. Also, we might allow anonymous users connecting to our system but they must adhere to the same security rules.

The solutions we found are:

- Use RabbitMQ's authentication and authorization system. We're not sure that it was designed to be this dynamic. Or was it?
- Create some kind of session for each user and use that random session key to name the user's exchange and/or queues. This way, only the user will know to which queues it should subscribe. It sounds secure enough for our needs. Is this the better approach?

Comment: what would be the reason for creating and destroying users continually?

Comment: Because of anonymous users. For each of them we thought that we could create a temporary RabbitMQ user with the required permission set.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more why you need to have an user account for an anonymous (i.e. unidentified) user ? Why a simple guest account won't fit your purposes ? Are you planning to use an user account to identify sessions ?

Comment: @user272735, I edited the original question to add more details. I hope it helps.